# загрузка структуры дерева TreeView из XML

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, treeview

Я пытаюсь отобразить элементы из XML в  TreeView используя wpf MVVM

**это мой XML:**

```
<Root>
    <Group GroupType = "Group1">
        <Table>
            <Name>TableName1.1</Name>       
            <Tag>TableTag1.1</Tag>
        </Table>
        <Table>
            <Name>TableName1.2</Name>       
            <Tag>TableTag1.2</Tag>
        </Table>
        <Group GroupType = "Group1.1">
            <Table>
                <Name>TableName1.1.1</Name>     
                <Tag>TableTag1.1.1</Tag>
            </Table>        
        </Group>
    </Group>
    <Group GroupType = "Group2">
        <Table>
            <Name>TableName2.1</Name>       
            <Tag>TableTag2.1</Tag>
        </Table>        
    </Group>
</Root>
```

**это моя ViewModel**

```
public class NavigationViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {
        private NavigationGroup _group;

        public NavigationViewModel()
        {
            _group = new NavigationGroup();
        }

        [XmlElement("Name", typeof(string))]
        public string Name
        {
            get
            {
                return _group.Name;
            }

            set
            {
                _group.Name = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Name");
            }
        }

        [XmlArray("Group")]
        [XmlArrayItem("Table")]
        public ObservableCollection<NavigationViewModel> Children { get; set; }
    }
```

**это моя model**

```
public class NavigationGroup
    {
        public string Name;
        public ObservableCollection<NavigationTable> Tables;

        public NavigationGroup()
        {
            Tables = new ObservableCollection<NavigationTable>();
        }
    }
```

**и конечно же XAML**

```
        <TreeView.ItemTemplate>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding  NavigVM.Children}"  >
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        </TreeView.ItemTemplate>
```

проблема заключается в том что отображаются только TableName. А как сделать так чтобы отображались еще  GroupType

```
Group1
    tableName1.1
    tableName1.2
    Group1.1
        TableName1.1.1
Group2
    TableName2.1
```

**небольшие изменения, спасибо VladD**

```
public class NavigationViewModel:ViewModelBase
    {


        public NavigationViewModel()
        {

        }





        private bool _isSelected;
        public bool isSelected
        {
            get
            {
                return _isSelected;
            }

            set
            {
                _isSelected = value;
            }
        }



        [XmlElement("Table")]
        public ObservableCollection<NavigationTable> Tables { get; set; }


        private ObservableCollection<NavigationGroup> _groups;
        [XmlElement("Group")]
        public ObservableCollection<NavigationGroup> Groups
        {
            get
            {
                return _groups;
            }

            set
            {
                _groups = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("Groups");
            }
        }



        **public List<object> Items**
        {
            get
            {
                List<object> childNodes = new List<object>();
                foreach (var group in this.Groups)
                    childNodes.Add(group);
                foreach (var entry in this.Tables)
                    childNodes.Add(entry);

                return childNodes;
            }
        }

    }
```

**XAML**

```
TreeView DataContext="{Binding NavigVM}" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  >

            <TreeView.Resources>
                <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NavigationGroup}" ItemsSource="{Binding items}">
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupType}" />
                </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
                <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NavigationTable}" >
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </TreeView.Resources>


        </TreeView>
```

но Treeview ничего не показывает

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну, для начала вам нужно `GroupType` положить в вашу модель и VM. Как у вас происходит десериализация?

Comment: @VladD Добрый вечер. мой код deserialization  'System.IO.StreamReader file =
            new System.IO.StreamReader("xmltables.xml");

            var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NavigationViewModel), new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "Root" });

            _navigVM= (NavigationViewModel)serializer.Deserialize(file);'

Comment: Хм, а у вас модель, кажется, вовсе не используется, вы десериализируете прямо VM.

Comment: Ну допустим. Тогда вам в классе `NavigationGroup` нужно положить свойство `GroupType` и точно так же протянуть его в `NavigationViewModel`. Только вместо `[XmlElement]` у вас будет `[XmlAttribute]`.

Comment: @VladD спасибо за помощь. Я уже пытался это сделать, но к сожалению, без успеха. deserialization Заваливается '[XmlAttribute("GroupType", typeof(string))]
        public string GroupType
        {
            get
            {
                return _group.GroupType;
            }

            set
            {
                _group.GroupType = value;
                this.OnPropertyChanged("GroupType");
            }
        }'

Comment: А что не так? Какая ошибка? Добавьте её в вопрос, это важно. (А я пока спать.)

Comment: @VladD ошибка: {"There was an error reflecting property 'GroupType'."} -2146233079

Comment: Хм, странно. А что в inner exception? Дайте больше информации.

Comment: @VladD inner exception: {"The type for XmlAttribute may not be specified for primitive types."} что это может значить?

Comment: Ну, уберите `typeof(string)`, пусть останется только `[XmlAttribute("GroupType")]`. Или вообще просто `[XmlAttribute]`.

Comment: @VladD очень странно , но ошибка больше не выскакивает. Но основная проблема остается Groups не загружаются. что-то я делаю не так с ViewModel , а как исправить не знаю

Comment: Подождите, у вас _один_ VM-класс `NavigationViewModel` соответствует и XML-тегу `Table`, и XML-тегу `Group`?

Comment: @VladD это же вложенные теги, поэтому Group = array -. Table = ArrayItem разве это неправильно?

Comment: @VladD Ну почему все должно быть так сложно c wpf + mvvm :) всё что мне нужно в конечном итоге это при нажатии TreeNode получить v ViewModel Selected object (current selected node + parent node + children nodes) и с этим я бьюсь  много дней :( И конечно-же структура дерева должна загружаться c XML

Comment: Там же всё просто. Ваша проблема — это не MVVM, это десериализация. Написал вам рабочий пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У меня десериализация работает вот так:

```
[XmlType]
public class Group
{
    [XmlElement("Table")]
    public List<Table> Tables { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Group")]
    public List<Group> Groups { get; set; }

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string GroupType { get; set; }
}

[XmlType]
public class Table
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

```
using (var file = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Group),
                                       new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "Root" });
    var result = (Group)serializer.Deserialize(file);
}
```

(Вам, понятно, нужно будет добавить `ViewModelBase` и реализацию `INotifyPropertyChanged`.)

---

**Обновление**:

С вот такими модификациями:

```
[XmlType]
public class NavigationGroup
{
    [XmlElement("Table")]
    public List<NavigationTable> Tables { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Group")]
    public List<NavigationGroup> Groups { get; set; }

    [XmlIgnore]
    public IEnumerable<object> Items => Tables.Cast<object>().Concat(Groups);

    [XmlAttribute]
    public string GroupType { get; set; }
}

[XmlType]
public class NavigationTable
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Tag { get; set; }
}
```

и десериализацией

```
using (var file = File.OpenRead(path))
{
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(NavigationGroup),
                           new XmlRootAttribute { ElementName = "Root" });
    var result = (NavigationGroup)serializer.Deserialize(file);
}
```

и вот таким XAML'ом:

```
<TreeView ItemsSource="{Binding Groups}">
    <TreeView.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NavigationGroup}"
                                  ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding GroupType}" Background="Green"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:NavigationTable}">
            <TextBlock Background="Yellow">
                <Run Text="{Binding Name}"/><Run Text="/"/><Run Text="{Binding Tag}"/>
            </TextBlock>
        </DataTemplate>
    </TreeView.Resources>
</TreeView>
```

получается следующая картинка:

[image: три-вью]

Comment: огромное спасибо за помочь. таким методам у меня тоже получилось, но идея была сделать  чтобы каждый childnode был ViewModel (тоесть создать иерархический ViewModel kak структура XML)

Comment: @Vadim: По идее, так тоже получится, просто у вас будет _два_ VM-класса: `NavigationGroupVM` и `TableVM`.

Comment: я немного изменил оригинальный ViewModel . не могли бы вы посмотреть на это пожалуйста

Comment: @Vadim: Ага, я гляну

Comment: TreeView не хочет нивкакую работать нормально

Comment: @Vadim: Дополнил ответ, смотрите.

Comment: огромное спасибо за помощь

Comment: @Vadim: Пожалуйста!

Comment: вы не знаете случайно что может повлиять на то что мое дерево не отображает GroupType and Name хотя видно place holders. я добавил картинку в моем оригинальном вопросе

Comment: @Vadim: Потому что у вас `Name` — это поле. Поля не работают с привязкой, поменяйте на свойство.